# MariaDB Query Optimizer ignores index

Tags: query-performance, mariadb, execution-plan

- MariaDB Version 10.5.15
- simple Table, two columns with an index

If I make a query on a table and use two columns in the where conndition that have an index, no index is used. Why?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `log_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(10) DEFAULT 0,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### Where date

```
analyze select count(*)
from logs 
where `date` < "2022-01-01 00:00:00"
```

uses index => 1.4s

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | logs | range | date | date | 6 |  | 5416235 | 7969250.00 | 100 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

### Where status

```
analyze select count(*)
from logs 
where status = 860
```

uses index => ~0.9s

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | logs | ref | status | status | 5 | const | 5416235 | 5536942.00 | 100 | 100 | Using index |

### Where date AND status

```
analyze select count(*)
from logs 
where status = 860
and `date` < "2022-01-01 00:00:00"
```

uses no index => ~7s

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | logs | ALL | status,date |  |  |  | 10832494 | 11430473.00 | 25 | 43.85 | Using where |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE logs
    DROP INDEX(status)
    ADD INDEX(status, date)
```

The added "composite" index will help both

```
WHERE status = ...
```

and

```
WHERE status = ... AND date < ...
```

and also

```
WHERE date < ... AND status = ...
```

Comment: Thank you, got it. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compound-composite-indexes/